# php Add to array that comes from function

Tags: php, arrays, function, web-services

I am breaking my head on this all day.
I am work with a Webservice and once I can get the array back one way or I get it back a different  way.
So I have a function that strips and pulls the data fro me.

this is the function.

```
function Detail($a){
            $age= array();
            $countArray = arrayCount($a);

        if ($countArray == 1){


                    array_push ($age,
                        array(
                        "Name"=>$a['Name'],
                         "ProductReference"=>$a['ProductReference'],
                          "AdicRange"=>$a['AdicRange'],
                          "Pages"=>$s['Pages']
                          );        

            }elseif($countArray >= 2){

         foreach ($a as $key => $d) {


            array_push ($age,
                array(
                "Name"=>$d['Name'],
                 "ProductReference"=>$d['ProductReference'],
                  "AdicRange"=>$d['AdicRange'],
                  "Pages"=>$d['Pages']
                 ) );


             }      

            }else{


            }


        return $age;
        }
```

I am trying t add to the array but I get the array back not correct.
This is the array I get back.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 21X29 booklet Ver
                    [ProductReference] => DF0754(A4)
                    [AdicRange] => 4
                    [Pages] => 24
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 35X35
                    [ProductReference] => FM8774
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 26X10
                    [ProductReference] => FM1032
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 21X29 booklet Hor
                    [ProductReference] => DF0750
                    [AdicRange] => 4
                    [Pages] => 24
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 35X35
                    [ProductReference] => FM8755
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 38X76
                    [ProductReference] => FM0099
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 50
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 40X80
                    [ProductReference] => FM7291
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 30X80
                    [ProductReference] => FM0058
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 20X60
                    [ProductReference] => FM1065
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

        )
)
```

Can some one please Help me.

I am trying to get the array back like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 40X80
                    [ProductReference] => FM7291
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 21X29 booklet Ver
                    [ProductReference] => DF0754(A4)
                    [AdicRange] => 4
                    [Pages] => 24
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 35X35
                    [ProductReference] => FM8774
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 26X10
                    [ProductReference] => FM1032
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 21X29 booklet Hor
                    [ProductReference] => DF0750
                    [AdicRange] => 4
                    [Pages] => 24
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 35X35
                    [ProductReference] => FM8755
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 38X76
                    [ProductReference] => FM0099
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 50
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 40X80
                    [ProductReference] => FM7291
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 30X80
                    [ProductReference] => FM0058
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 20X60
                    [ProductReference] => FM1065
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 20
                )
         [9] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => pro book 40X80
                    [ProductReference] => FM7291
                    [AdicRange] => 2
                    [Pages] => 
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: your question is not clear. what you want can you give example?

Comment: What's the logic behind your expected array ?

Comment: I have to send a array as the example ant the and of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a closing parenthesis within your first if clause.

```
function Detail($a) {
$age = array();
$countArray = arrayCount($a);

if ($countArray == 0) {


    array_push ($age,
    array(
    "Name" => $a['Name'],
    "ProductReference" => $a['ProductReference'],
    "AdicRange" => $a['AdicRange'],
    "Pages" => $s['Pages']
    ));
} elseif ($countArray >= 1) {

    foreach ($a as $key => $d) {


        array_push($age, array(
            "Name" => $d['Name'],
            "ProductReference" => $d['ProductReference'],
            "AdicRange" => $d['AdicRange'],
            "Pages" => $d['Pages']
        ));
    }
} else {

}


return $age;
}
```

Comment: Same result No change

Comment: @DaniEvanRubenstein I updated my answer copy & paste try again. Let me know.

Comment: No its not ok. the countArray has to me as i posted it. the webservive that I am using it not so good. have a lock at this post and that is way I am doing it like this. thanks. [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457939/php-array-count-in-with-dynamic-result